# Not finding header files while compiling thrust example code

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, gpu

I downloaded thrust 1.70 and 1.60 from thrust [webpage](http://thrust.github.io) to my home directory, `/home/me/project/thrust`. When I try to run the [example](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/) below, using `gcc -c  -I/home/me/project thrust_1_example.cpp` , I received error messages that header files are not found: `In file included from /home/me/project/thrust/detail/config.h:22,
                 from /home/me/project/thrust/host_vector.h:24,
                 from thrust_1_example.cpp:1:
/home/me/project/thrust/detail/config/config.h:25:49: error: thrust/detail/config/simple_defines.h: No such file or directory`

I found that `detail/config` is indeed empty. Am I missing something?

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    // H has storage for 4 integers
    thrust::host_vector<int> H(4);

    // initialize individual elements
    H[0] = 14;
    H[1] = 20;
    H[2] = 38;
    H[3] = 46;

    // H.size() returns the size of vector H
    std::cout << "H has size " << H.size() << std::endl;

    // print contents of H
    for(int i = 0; i < H.size(); i++)
        std::cout << "H[" << i << "] = " << H[i] << std::endl;

    // resize H
    H.resize(2);

    std::cout << "H now has size " << H.size() << std::endl;

    // Copy host_vector H to device_vector D
    thrust::device_vector<int> D = H;

    // elements of D can be modified
    D[0] = 99;
    D[1] = 88;

    // print contents of D
    for(int i = 0; i < D.size(); i++)
        std::cout << "D[" << i << "] = " << D[i] << std::endl;

    // H and D are automatically deleted when the function returns
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply install CUDA 5.5 you will get thrust 1.7.

If you are targeting a GPU backend (meaning you want to run your thrust code on the GPU) it requires `nvcc`, the GPU device code compiler/compiler driver, which comes with CUDA 5.5.

You cannot build thrust GPU code with `gcc` (you must use `nvcc`) and the file name should end in `.cu` not `.cpp`

Comment: After I renamed the file to .cu and compiled it, I tried to run with g++, `gcc -c -I/home/me/project thrust_1_example.o`
and get an error `gcc: square_cuda.o: linker input file unused because linking not done`. I read that there should be a wrapper c++ file, but this example already contains main().

Comment: you cannot use `g++` or `gcc` to compile (`-c`) a thrust file that targets the GPU.  Furthermore it makes no sense to try and compile a `.o` file that has already been compiled.  You seem to be confused about how to use the tools to do compile and linking.  If you have cuda 5.5 installed, compile your program with `nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o square_cuda square_cuda.cu`  When you want to run the program, run it by typing the compiled file name: `./square_cuda`